# How to merge NamedTuples in in a macro in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to do a `JSON.mapping` in a class (`OtherThing`) based on the merge of two named tuples.

```
class Thing
  MAPPING = {
    id:                  {type: String, default: UUID.random.to_s},
    email:               {type: String, nilable: true},
  }

  JSON.mapping({{MAPPING}})
end

class OtherThing
  MAPPING = Thing::MAPPING.merge({
    address:                              String,
    city:                                 String,
    zip:                                  {type: String, nilable: true},
    latitude:                             {type: Float64, nilable: true},
    longitude:                            {type: Float64, nilable: true},
  })

  JSON.mapping({{MAPPING}})
end
```

This produces an error depending on how I organize the code.

One error:

```
Error expanding macro

FOR expression must be an array, hash or tuple literal, not Call:

Thing::MAPPING.merge

{% for key, value in _properties_ %}
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Another possible error:

`undefined macro method 'NamedTupleLiteral#merge'` in the `JSON.mapping` of `OtherThing`

Answer (score 0):

In short answer — no, you can't interpolate constant in macro right now.

@asterite:

> The problem is that the mapping macros expect a HashLiteral as an
>   argument, but now they receive a Path

In you case instead NamedTuple macro got the Call node. In discuss on Crystal repo https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/2388 found workaround that in theory can solve this problem but JSON.mapping it is old method and will be removed from language in next versions, instead try to [JSON::Serializable](https://devdocs.io/crystal/api/0.27.0/json/serializable)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Blacksmoke16 for his help in pointing that, you can achieve desired outcome by defining your own macro with splats.

Below code should work. Credit goes to @Blacksmoke16

```
macro define(*args)
  JSON.mapping(    
    {% for t in args %}
      {{t.double_splat}},
    {% end %}
  )
end

class Thing
  MAPPING = {
    id:                  {type: String, default: UUID.random.to_s},
    email:               {type: String, nilable: true},
  }

  define {{MAPPING}}
end

class OtherThing
  MAPPING = {
    address:                              String,
    city:                                 String,
    zip:                                  {type: String, nilable: true},
    latitude:                             {type: Float64, nilable: true},
    longitude:                            {type: Float64, nilable: true},
  }

  define {{MAPPING}}, {{Thing::MAPPING}}
end
```